# Instance variable assigned in initializer wrongly inferred as nilable

Tags: crystal-lang

Using Crystal 0.25.1 the type of the instance variable `@foo` in this example is inferred to be nil-able even though it can never be `nil`:

```
class Foo
end

class Bar
  def initialize(foo : Foo? = nil)
    @foo = foo || Foo.new
  end
end

p typeof(Bar.new.@foo) # => (Foo | Nil)
```

I know that I can declare `@foo : Foo` at the class level, to work around the issue, but why can't the Crystal compiler infer that `@foo` can never be `nil` on its own?

Comment: The rule comes from here: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/type_inference.html#3-assigning-a-variable-that-is-a-method-argument-with-a-type-restriction . You have something like `@foo = foo` and `foo : Foo?` in the method argument, so `@foo` is inferred to be `Foo?`. It doesn't matter that there's `||`, that type of "inference" comes much later. So you have to say `@foo : Foo`.

Comment: It's probably best to avoid this pattern in Crystal by using overloads or assigning the default to the method argument directly.

Comment: @asterite Thanks for the explanation. Would you like to post that as an answer or should I answer my own question?